# UV Map looks correct but texture not applying properly around Corner

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, geometry

I modelled a simple road with a roughly 90 degree rounded turn/corner.

To create the UV map I marked seems along the edges of the top Faces, unwrapped, selected a quad and then applied "follow active quads" to straighten the UV map so textures will follow the direction of the road.

[image]

Close up of UV map

[image]

However when I apply a texture map in Unreal Engine you can see the Y axis is skewed and intersecting itself along the corner.

[image]

What did I do wrong and how do i fix this?

Comment: If you bend a texture, it bends. I don't understand what the expectation here is. If you had more geometry in the mesh, the deformation might look nicer, but if you don't want it deformed, the texture should be made for the UV map without straightening the bending UVs.

Comment: Ah i see. I was expecting it go across the faces on the bend the same way the edge topology does

Comment: https://youtu.be/BfR-aA-zy9g?si=f1IuUkfJIFM2tVww just like what happens in this video

Comment: It does. You have different topology. Or do you mean you are not happy with the artefacts? More geometry will fix them. If you don't have enough points, the deformation cannot be done smoothly. Try subdividing it with Subdivision Surface modifier and see how it improves(just to see it, it might be more efficient to only add geometry where you need it manually or at least remove the unneeded loops after subdivision).